# setSoftInputMode() in a ViewPager - unexpected behavior

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard, android-windowmanager

I have 2 fragments in a ViewPager and I want the window to adjust differently to the soft keyboard on the 2nd fragment. Here's what I'm trying:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if(position == 1){  // desired for 2nd fragment
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
    } else {  // desired for 1st fragment
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_UNSPECIFIED);
    }
}
```

Observed behavior:

- Enter 1st fragment and default `softInputMode` is working, as expected.
- Swipe to 2nd fragment and breakpoint shows that the `softInputMode` should be set to `ADJUST_NOTHING`, *but everything still behaves like the default*.
- Swipe *back* to 1st fragment and it behaves with `ADJUST_NOTHING`.
- Swiping back and forth now reveals both fragments to behave like `ADJUST_NOTHING`, even though breakpoints show these calls are being made.

To top it off, I can switch fragments all I want and the input mode will behave as default until I pull up the soft keyboard. Then it starts its migration toward `ADJUST_NOTHING`. I'm quite baffled.

I don't have any relevant flags in the manifest, although in my Activity `onCreate()` I do set the input mode to `SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN`.

Comment: @Yvette, can you clarify what you mean by my fragment calls? Do you mean the lifecycle callbacks?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found works well enough, although I hope there's a smoother way out there somewhere. I did two things.

First, I stopped using `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_UNSPECIFIED`as my "default" input state because the WindowManager seems to treat changes to and from this state a bit differently. 'SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE' gives the behavior I desire, so I changed my method to

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
    );
    hide_keyboard(activity);
    if(position == 1){  // desired for 2nd fragment
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
    } else {  // desired for 1st fragment
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    }
}
```

This fixed the "getting stuck in a certain input mode" issue. Still, I wasn't getting the input mode I wanted on my 2nd fragment, so I added a callto set the input mode right before launching the DialogFragments with text input fields from my 2nd fragment.

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING); // fragment behind doesn't get readjusted from keyboard.
editCatFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "editCatFrag");
```

This actually doesn't guarantee the mode I want the first time the fragment is launched, but makes it work the 2nd time which, due to how my app is designed, actually works out okay.

Hopefully this helps someone and hopefully there's a better way of solving this problem. Thanks!